# Cannot Edit Free Downloaded Model of Blender?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I am new to Blender and cannot edit a model in and it was in .blend format because there is no *Layout* or *Modeling* tab in Blender 2.9.

[image]

Comment: The "+" button in the top bar?

Comment: you can unfold the panels but just click on the Default tab

Comment: Open Blender, use *File > Open* to get the file browser, click on the cog wheel for options, disable *Load UI*, then load the project file.

Comment: If you are ¨new to blender" I would advise to learn the basic use of the interface. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/index.html before you get into more advanced topics.